# How do I link a User with a django model as soon as the User is created?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am new to Django and my question is how do I link a Django `User` with the `Climber` model that I created as soon as the user is registered? So far, I can register a new `User` with Django's builtin user registration form. But when I go into my admin page I see that I have to create a new `Climber` manually and select which `User` I want it to link to. Thank you in advance!

```
class Climber(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grades = [('v'+str(i),'v'+str(i))for i in range(0,13)]
    highest_grade = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=grades, default='v0')
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    climbs_completed = models.ManyToManyField(Climb, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    # for each climbs_completed, sum up the points
    def total_score(self):
        pass
```

Comment: check django signals - add `post_save` signal.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save).

Example:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Climber

User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Climber.objects.create(user=instance, ...)
```

Another way is to override the `clean()` or `save()` method of the `User`-model, considered that you have a custom user model yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/)

Create function in models Climber

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def link_climber(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """ If new user is created, create climber for him """
    if created:
        Climber.objects.create(user=instance)
```